# What language is this in The Witcher: Blood Origin series?

Tags: the-witcher, the-witcher-blood-origins

In the Netflix mini series *The Witcher: Blood Origin* we see the names of places written in some different language what language is it?

[image]

The English translation of it is given below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The subtitles at the sequence with the introduction of the character known as Lark is [Elder-Speech](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Elder_Speech), written in [Elder-Runic](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Elder_Runes).

Much is known of the language as it was invented by the [Author](https://witcher.fandom.com/wiki/Andrzej_Sapkowski) and developed into a fully consistent constructed-language for the screen by renowned linguist [David J. Peterson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/David_J._Peterson). It draws heavily on Celtic from the Irish and Welsh languages with some Scottish, with some connotations being taken from German and English. There are occasional Latin and Italian words such as the verbs "to be" and "to have".

The textual form of Elder Runes are as in the original book, and remain undeveloped fully and with all the quirks and inconsistencies it started with.

Inis is the Irish word for "island".

Dubh is the Irish word for "black".

*Black Island*- Found in the far northern seas.